# How can I loop through observations and values in the dataset?

Tags: sas

I need to loop through a dataset (built-in, training SAS table with data) and do some calculations based on it. First off, I don't know how I could loop through values in range of columns of the table. Second, need to loop through all values in every observation and calculate difference between previous and following value. Here is the example of a table:

```
Auto   Price1  Price2  Price3 
Mazda  35.000  40.500  38.000
Audi   70.000  60.000  80.000
BMW    110.000 85.000  93.000
```

Let's say my table is named Prices in SAS. I tried below but I know it's totally wrong. I have no idea how to start:

```
data data.Prices;

set myDataset.Prices;
do price_prev = Price1;
    do price_next = Price2;

    end;
    end;

    result = price_next-price_prev;
 run;
```

Desired output should be as follows:

```
Auto   Diff1   Diff2    Diff3 
Mazda  0       5.500    -2.500
Audi   0       -10.000  20.000
BMW    0       -25.000  8.000
```

I need do use some kind of a loop but don't know how. Important thing is that I can't use macros or some other complex synthax. Just loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the DATA step, data set *columns* are known as *variables*.

The `ARRAY` statement is used to associate variables to an array name that can use index referencing syntax *name[index]*.  The array default is 1-based (first element is at `[1]`).

```
ARRAY prices price1-price3;
```

If the variable names associated to an array name do not already exist the statement causes the variables to be added to the program data vector (PDV).

```
ARRAY diffs diff1-diff3;
```

Once you have the arrays specified you can loop over the number of items in the array (`DIM` function)

```
* compute difference from prior price;
diffs[1] = 0;
do index = 2 to dim (prices);
  diffs[index] = prices[index] - prices[index-1];
end;
```

If you have more than 3 prices, like 10, just change the 3's to 10's.

Comment: Great! This is what i was looking for:) So, basically I always need to 'transform' SAS table (dataset) into ARRAY as to associate variables. Then I can loop. Thanks!

Comment: Your vocabulary is a little 'off' from SAS nomenclature, but I think you understand.  During data step the columns of a row can be arrayed per your specification.  In the simplest take, you are not transforming anything except the method of referencing a column.  Array specification and use can be a lot more complicated, subtle and useful as you learn more about the DATA step and the program data vector. (Such as temporary arrays and effects of RETAIN on new or set variables when proceeding to the next row)